# how to get total records with a previous filter in a Sencha Touch app?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

Working with an application based in Sencha Touch I need to get total amount of a store but with a previous filter implemented.

I can do `store.getCount()` and to know the total records of a store, but How to know total records with a previous filter?

Comment: can you send some code here what you want to do? I can help you.

Comment: Simply, I want to filter, for example, by name and get the count of this.. Imagine how many records has the name "Billy"...  thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution :

```
var count = 0;

store.findBy(function(rec) {
    if (rec.get('myFilter')) {
        count++; // Only counting matching data
    }
});

console.log(count); // Total amount of filtered data
```

From : https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?174156-Store-count-by-criteria-without-filter

Comment: I can't see why this is the correct answer. First, I would suggest replacing the `findBy` with an `each` if you want to do it this way. Second, `if(rec.get('myFilter'))` can only work if you are checking on a boolean value. The answer you refer to is more then 3 years old, and is also checking on boolean value.Now-a-days you can use `query` (for extjs or `queryby` (for Touch).

Answer (score 0):

If the store is filtered [`getCount()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getCount) will retrieve the amount of records based on your filter. If you filter on 'Billy', the `getCount()` will return only 2 if there are 2 'Billy's'.

From the docs:

> Gets the number of records in store.
>
> If using paging, this may not be the total size of the dataset. If the
>   data object used by the Reader contains the dataset size, then the
>   Ext.data.ProxyStore.getTotalCount function returns the dataset size.
>   Note: see the Important note in Ext.data.ProxyStore.load.
>
> When store is filtered, it's the number of records matching the
>   filter.

If you want to get the total amount of records you can use [`getTotalCount()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getTotalCount). This will count all records, no matter if it's filtered or not.

From the docs:

> Returns the total number of Model instances that the Proxy indicates
>   exist. This will usually differ from getCount when using paging -
>   getCount returns the number of records loaded into the Store at the
>   moment, getTotalCount returns the number of records that could be
>   loaded into the Store if the Store contained all data

If you want to query over the store you can use [`queryBy`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-queryBy). This will return a collection of records. You can then use [`getCount()`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.util.MixedCollection-method-getCount) over the collection.

```
var billies = store.queryBy(function(rec, id) {
    return rec.get('name') === 'billy';
});

billies.getCount();
```

Comment: yes, but definitely I need to filter previously with the method specified by @Benoit .. I will get your recommendation about the getCount and getTotalCount.... Thank you!